# Is there a way to get Visual Studio to unload dlls?

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-studio-2008, dll

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project with some legacy native C++ DLL projects, and some newer WPF projects that use the DLLs.  When I open the WPF xaml windows in the designer, Visual Studio loads up the native DLLs to be able to display the window.

The problem is, is that if I now need to make a change in the legacy DLLs, I need to close all the WPF windows and restart visual studio to be able to build them.  Obviously, I need to close the tabs that are using the DLLs, but after I do that, is there a way to tell Visual Studio to unload those DLLs without a full restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems.  A little bit better than restarting is removing references to the dlls, then adding the references back in.

Comment: I just tried this in VS 2015 and it doesn't help unload a COM DLL. Nor did closing the solution, only closing VS seems to do it.

Comment: I've now found that VS2015 only holds the DLL loaded if you run the project (without debugging), if you debug the project, you can replace the DLL as soon as it stops. I wondered for a while why it seemed intermittent - this was the difference. (My project is a Unit Test project, so I'm not F5ing, I'm running the tests either Run or Debug.)

Comment: @scipilot: Interesting.  I wonder if the problem would still occur during debugging if you [disabled vshost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in VS.  You could try getting VS 2008 SP1 to see if that fixes it.
Otherwise, go here and report it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.  They'll help with any workaround if there is one.